# What is this property to be called?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, terminology, functional-equations

Two functions, $f$ and $g$, that satisfy the following identity: $$f(g(a_1,...,a_n), g(b_1,...,b_n),...) = g(f(a_1,b_1,....), f(a_2,b_2,...)...)$$
(notice the "transposition" of the arguments), do they possess a named and/or known property? Or as an alternative, where can I find out more about it?

(Apologies if I asked a duplicate question, but I didn't know how to search for it)

Comment: Maybe it would be helpful to write it $f\left(g(A^1),g(A^2),\ldots ,g(A^n)\right)=g\left(f(A_1),f(A_2),\ldots , f(A_n)\right)$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition#Multivariate_functions) calls it "*$f$ and $g$ commute*" for multivariate functions:

> The notion of commutation also finds an interesting generalization in the multivariate case; a function $f$ of arity $n$ is said to commute with a function $g$ of arity $m$ if $f$ is a homomorphism preserving $g$, and vice versa i.e.:
>   $${f\big(g(a_{11},\ldots ,a_{1m}),\ldots ,g(a_{n1},\ldots ,a_{nm})\big)=g\big(f(a_{11},\ldots ,a_{n1}),\ldots ,f(a_{1m},\ldots ,a_{nm})\big)}
> $$

The given reference is [*Universal Algebra: Fundamentals and Selected Topics*](https://books.google.com/books?id=QXi3BZWoMRwC&pg=PA90#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Clifford Bergman.

Comment: This was definitely reminding me of universal algebra stuff. *shudders* Good find.

Comment: It is called *Bisymmetry* in the context of  functional equations.

Comment: @JensSchwaiger Thanks for that tidbit. You should post it as an answer, perhaps with some reference.

Answer (score 2):

In section 5 of
https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.imbs.uci.edu/files/personnel/luce/2000/AczelFalmagneLuce_Mathematica%2520Japonica_2000.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjS_cWRuqXcAhWNZ1AKHZ7BDGwQFjAEegQIAhAB&usg=AOvVaw3WLjcxovgzVUfeuIABNdBJ

you my find this equation of *generalized* bisymmetry.